# SimpleXML Parser android getting HTML TAG

Tags: android, xml, parsing, simple-framework

I have a TAG getinng the whole description is getting difficult in SimpleXML what property should i give to get whole description.
SimpleXML is parssing the p tag also .

```
<description>
<p>

 Bar In Inconel</p> <ul> <li>600</li> <li>601</li> <li>617</li> <li>625</li> <li>718/718 NACE MRO</li> <li>725</li> <li>800</li> <li>825</li> <li>925</li> <li>K500</li> <li>MP35N</li> <li>X750</li> <li>C276</li></ul> <p>Aluminum Tubing, Aluminum Pipe, Aluminum Sheet, Aluminum Bar, Aluminum Plate In Aluminum</p> <ul> <li>2219</li> <li>2024</li> <li>2124</li> <li>3003</li> <li>5052</li> <li>6061</li> <li>7075</li> <li>7050</li></ul> <p>Stainless Steel In Tube, Pipe, Plate, Sheet &amp;

</p>
</description>
```

Comment: so do you want to store only the text in a string without html tag?

Comment: no with the html tag
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'p' does not have a match.This is the exception i want description that should give the whole string with the html tag

Comment: @Element(name = "description", required = false, data = true)
 public String description; 
This isn't working

Answer (score 3):

When getting final response just enclose the CDATA tag and make the data=true for that element

```
str = str.replaceAll("<description>","<description><![CDATA[");
str = str.replace("</description>", "]]></description>");
```

:D :D
:D

Comment: You can click the tick on your answer (below vote count) -- see here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/